# Azure Function App Error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' when extracting a data from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, debugging, azure-functions

There is a sudden error from the function app I developed where I used the .get() method to extract data from a dictionary. Here is the sample code I used:

```
def sendOpenAIPromptRequest(azureopenai_endpoint, azureopenai_deployment,azureopenai_token, azureopenai_version, workItemDetails):
    workItemSummary = []

    #Iteration per object in workItemDetails
    for item in workItemDetails:
        openai_prompt = openAIPrompt(item)
        try:
            url =  f"{azureopenai_endpoint}/openai/deployments/{azureopenai_deployment}/chat/completions?{azureopenai_version}"
            headers = {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "Authorization": f"Bearer {azureopenai_token}"
                        }
            body = {
                                "max_tokens": 590,
                                "messages": [
                                    {
                                        "role": "user", 
                                        "content": openai_prompt
                                    }
                                ],
                                "temperature": 0.25
                    }
            response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, json=body)
            print(response)
            responseContent = json.loads(response.text)
            
        except:
            return print("An error has occurred.")
        container = {
            "UserStoryId": item.get("UserStoryId", ""),
            "UserStoryTitle": item.get("UserStoryTitle", ""),
            "UserStoryState":item.get("UserStoryState", ""),
            "UserStoryType": item.get("UserStoryType", ""),
            "Summary": responseContent['choices'][0]['message']['content']
        }
        
        workItemSummary.append(container)
    
    return json.dumps({"workItemSummaryValue": workItemSummary})
```

workItemDetails is a list of dictionaries where I need to transfer its data to the "container" variable.

```
workItemDetails = [
{
            "UserStoryId": "id1",
            "UserStoryTitle": "title1",
            "UserStoryState": "state1",
            "UserStoryType": "type1"
            "RawUpdates": "updates1",
            "RawComments": "comments1"
        },
{
            "UserStoryId": "id2",
            "UserStoryTitle": "title2",
            "UserStoryState": "state2",
            "UserStoryType": "type2"
            "RawUpdates": "updates2",
            "RawComments": "comments2"
        }]
```

It worked fine for the past few weeks but when I run it again from the VScode or from the deployed application, it will return this error:

`[2023-11-09T23:41:43.106Z] Executed 'Functions.MyFunctionApp' (Failed, Id=d91f7dc1-8c42-477d-a506-6128fd5e6898, Duration=10120ms) [2023-11-09T23:41:43.109Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.MyFunctionApp. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure Exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`

Please help me with this.

I need to transfer a data from a dictionary to another dictionary variable in Azure Function app.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, workItemDetails is a list of dictionaries which I need to itemize to access the keys inside.

Comment: workItemDetails may be shown like this:

```workItemDetails = [
{
            "UserStoryId": "id1",
            "UserStoryTitle": "title1",
            "UserStoryState": "state1",
            "UserStoryType": "type1"
            "RawUpdates": "updates1",
            "RawComments": "comments1"
        },
{
            "UserStoryId": "id2",
            "UserStoryTitle": "title2",
            "UserStoryState": "state2",
            "UserStoryType": "type2"
            "RawUpdates": "updates2",
            "RawComments": "comments2"
        }]```

Comment: I edited my post to show the workItemDetail data

Comment: yes. my code works in the local python file. However, when I run it through the Azure Function App using 'func start' command in the terminal, it will return the error.

Comment: _workItemDetails is a list of dictionaries_ Are you sure of this?  As a debugging step, try printing `item` at the top of the loop.

Comment: `UserStoryType` is still missing a comma after its value in the text that you posted. Are you sure that it's a `list` of `dict` when it reaches your code?

Comment: @LaggyFingers was your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type of your data by:

```
for item in workItemDetails:
  print(type(item))
```

---

I assume your `workItemDetails` is coming like this:

```
workItemDetails = ['{ "UserStoryId": "id1","UserStoryTitle": "title1","UserStoryState": "state1", "UserStoryType": "type1","RawUpdates": "updates1","RawComments": "comments1"}',
'{"UserStoryId": "id2","UserStoryTitle": "title2","UserStoryState": "state2","UserStoryType": "type2","RawUpdates": "updates2","RawComments": "comments2"}']
```

Now, if you do:

```
for item in workItemDetails:
  container = {
            "UserStoryId": item.get("UserStoryId", ""),
            "UserStoryTitle": item.get("UserStoryTitle", ""),
            "UserStoryState":item.get("UserStoryState", ""),
            "UserStoryType": item.get("UserStoryType", ""),
            
        }
```

you will get this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-a611593be7a6> in <cell line: 1>()
      1 for item in workItemDetails:
      2   container = {
----> 3             "UserStoryId": item.get("UserStoryId", ""),
      4             "UserStoryTitle": item.get("UserStoryTitle", ""),
      5             "UserStoryState":item.get("UserStoryState", ""),

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

---

Workaround:

```
from ast import literal_eval
workItemDetails = [literal_eval(item) for item in workItemDetails]

for item in workItemDetails:
    container = {
            "UserStoryId": item.get("UserStoryId", ""),
            "UserStoryTitle": item.get("UserStoryTitle", ""),
            "UserStoryState":item.get("UserStoryState", ""),
            "UserStoryType": item.get("UserStoryType", ""),
            
        }

print(container)

{'UserStoryId': 'id2',
 'UserStoryTitle': 'title2',
 'UserStoryState': 'state2',
 'UserStoryType': 'type2'}
```